# jQuery fadeIn for thumbnail images in a div - code not working

Tags: jquery, css, image, html, fadein

I have a `div` that holds a bunch of thumbnail images. Each image has the `rel` attribute specified and I would like to use that value to pop up the full size image of the thumbnail in another div.

I want to use the `jQuery fadeIn` function. My code isn't working..and I don't know jQuery very well at all.

What's wrong with this code?

```
<html>

<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
.imgdiv {

    /* initially overlay is hidden */
    display:none;

</style>    

</head>

<body>

    <div id="book">
    <img src="thumbnails/book1.png" width="100" height="123" rel="photo1"/>

    <img src="thumbnails/book2.png" width="100" height="123" rel="photo2"/>
    </div>


<div class="imgdiv" id="photo1">
    <img src="thumbnails/booklarge1.png" />
</div>

<div class="imgdiv" id="photo2">
    <img src="thumbnails/booklarge2.png" />
</div>        

<script>
    $('#book img').click(function() {      
      $('#book img[rel]').fadeIn('slow'); 
    });       

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first in your `rel` tag you need to have `#` in front so its looks for the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code inside your click function to this

`$("#"+$(this).attr("rel")).fadeIn('slow');`

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zV2PH/)

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. I greatly appreciate the example link so I could see exactly how the code should be.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
 $('#book > img').click(function() {      
      $("div.imgdiv").hide();
      $(this).fadeIn('slow'); 
 });
```

Comment: gives an error `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]
Source File: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
Line: 4179`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using html5 data attribute over `rel`. Something like `data-largeimage="#photo1"`

Also, define the click event in a document ready function: `$(function(){ //do stuff })`

Extension of Naveed's code:

```
$(function(){

 $('#book > img').click(function() {      
  $("div.imgdiv").hide();
  var largeImage = $(this).data('largeimage');
  $(largeImage ).fadeIn('slow'); 

 }); 

});
```

If you would like to use your old selector, change `$('#book img[rel]')` to `$('#book img[rel="' + variable + '"]')`